# How can I transmit the $exercise parameter without overriding it?

Tags: php, symfony

Here is the function that find the first exercise with the certain `lessonid`

```
public function exerciseAction($lessonid, $exercise)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$exercise = $em->getRepository('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Exercise')->findOneByLesson($lessonid);

return $this->render('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Page:exercise.html.twig', array(
        'exercise' => $exercise,
        'lessonid' => $lessonid,
    ));
}
```

Here I try to implement a function to al the exercises one by one

```
public function exercisePagerAction($exercise)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $nextExercise= $em->getRepository('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Exercise')->getNext($exercise);

    return $this->render('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Page:exercise.html.twig', array(
        'exercise' => $nextExercise,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$nextExercise= $em->getRepository('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Exercise')->getNext($exercise);
```

You need to find sth.

```
$nextExercise= $em->getRepository('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Exercise')->findOneById($exercise)->getNext();
```

Comment: yes but how can i do this... because my variable $exercise depends on $lessonid

Comment: But you got primiarykey in excercise so whats the problem?

Comment: the problem is here  $exercise = $em->getRepository('PrezentariPrezentariBundle:Exercise')->findOneByLesson($lessonid); because it is overriding my $exercise

Comment: getNext is a getter for the relation to next entity Excercise?

Comment: public function getNext($exercise)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('exercise')
            ->andWhere('exercise.id > ?0')
            ->orderBy('exercise.id', 'ASC')
            ->setParameters(array(
            $exercise->getId(),
        ))
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery();

        $result = $query->getResult();

        $nextExercise = null;
        if ($result) {
            $nextExercise = $result[0];
        }

        return $nextExercise;
    }